# Is it a bug for method hash#to_json in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I use rails 2.3.8

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => ({ :results => @posts.size, :rows => @posts.to_json(:only => [:id, :title, :click_count, :body])}).to_json }
    end
  end
```

the generated json data is:

> {"rows":**"**[{\"title\":\"ruby\",\"body\":\"goood\",\"click_count\":1,\"id\":1},{\"title\":\"g\",\"body\":\"h\",\"click_count\":1,\"id\":2}]**"**,"results":2}

but in fact is shuld be:

> {"rows":[{\"title\":\"ruby\",\"body\":\"goood\",\"click_count\":1,\"id\":1},{\"title\":\"g\",\"body\":\"h\",\"click_count\":1,\"id\":2}],"results":2}

is it a bug in rails?

and now how can to_json generate the expected json data for me?

Thanks!

Comment: The two are exactly the same.

Comment: @stephenjudkins: the `rows` array in the first example is enclosed in quotes. Is that still a JSON array? (I'm clueless myself, just asking.)

Comment: @stephp,no ,it is not the same,becase I test it in extjs grid panel,the second json data is working ,but failed for the first.

[] quoted is not js array,it string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,it was my fault.

the action code should be

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => ({ :results => @posts.size, :rows => @posts.map{|x| x.attributes}).to_json } }
    end
  end
```

That is to say: the value of key :rows must be an array object!

Thanks hoooopo!